# What are the stuffed toys in Suguha's room?

Tags: sword-art-online, mawaru-penguindrum

Kirigaya Suguha's room is often portrayed in the ALO arc of Sword Art Online.

When Suguya is in her room, some stuffed toys are visible in the background.

[image: Sword Art Online]

[image: Sword Art Online]

Penguins resemble those from [Mawaru Penguindrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguindrum), even available as stuffed toys:

[image: Penguindrum stuffed toys]

However, the animation studio is different and the link between the two shows is not clear to me.

What are these stuffed toys? Are these a citation of other anime or universes related to Sword Art Online production?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the cat-looking things in front are a type of nesting doll (matryoshka doll). Specifically this:

*From http://bobobabushka.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/lucky-new-year/*

[image: http://bobobabushka.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/maneki-neko-set.jpg]

The Penguins themselves might be a generic penguin plush toy. Remember that people keep all sorts of things in their bedrooms, and wouldn't display anything they didn't find visually appealing. Plush toys are considered cute.

In the first image, the dog-like stuffed animals are Capybara-san. This is also a cute thing.

If you want to make a connection. Capybara-san and Mawaru Penguindrum are toys put out by Banpresto, who also puts out SAO figurines.

Answer (score 1):

Those cat-like dolls kinda looks like Kapibarasan. A doll popular in Japan. I have one as well and the salesclerk told me they were Suguha's dolls.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing special about them, they are just random animal plush as such thing are popular toys for kids. Stuffed animals are often shaped as people's favorite animals and such things.